# Port forwarding on a custom created network on VMWare

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, vmware

I have an Ubuntu 16 Machine up and running using a static IP on VMWare.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
    address 172.16.234.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.16.234.0
    broadcast 172.16.234.255
    gateway 172.16.234.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Then I created and assinged a new custom created network to this VM:

[image]

Now when I try to do `ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 3000` it says "Connection Refused". Can you guys help me on this?

Comment: Check ssh port is up with netstate -ntpl | grep 3000

Comment: Please check firewall may it dropped

Comment: Firewall is off @mohammadmoeini

Comment: Port is not shown @mohammadmoeini

Comment: please check  windows firewall, advanced TCP/IP filtering was enabled to only allow a few ports (nic > properties > TCP/IP > advanced > options > TCP/IP filtering) , please fix it